# Did Matt Damon actually lose weight for The Martian?

Tags: the-martian

Did Matt Damon lose weight to look that skinny in The Martian or was that a body double?

Comment: No actor would drop that kind of weight and then cover his face with a towel during the shot. Moreover, it doesn't make sense on the actor's part to put so much effort for a barebody scene that lasts probably 5 seconds.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher Plenty of actors have done extreme weight loss for movies. The Machinist comes to mind.

Comment: @cde I think you missed my point bud. What I was trying to imply was that in this particular scenario it didn't make sense for Damon to loose weight for the scene. The effort was not worth it. Actors do lose wight for movies all the time though!

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher if you see the quote in my answer, Ridley may agree with you on the effort/sense part, but Damon would have had no issue with it. :)

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher - Tom Hanks, Cast Away.  Seems like almost an identical scenario.  What seems reasonable or sane to you or I does not necessarily compute the same with artistic types, or those who fancy themselves artistic types, however, the answer below renders that mute.

Comment: @Sayan they also put on weight.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[No. According to Bustle](http://www.bustle.com/articles/112961-how-much-weight-did-matt-damon-lose-for-the-martian-thankfully-the-actors-transformation-was-computer-helped) (The interview was a press Q&A on set):

> "I talked to [Director] Ridley about [losing weight for The Martian] because I’ve lost weight before for movies," Damon told Newsweek. "We had about six months. And I said, 'That’s perfect. I’ll lose about 30 or 40 pounds, and we’ve got to shoot all that stuff first.'
>   **And he went, 'Fuck that.'**"

There was no information to if it was a body double, none was listed in the credits. The article above believes it was cgi and shows various examples.

As an example, Chris Evans in Captain America was also had a CGI based body that was even more extreme than Damon's, showing how advance and realistic the effects can be.

Comment: Pre-Captain America Steve Rodgers.  That was some pretty amazing CGI.